# Creating loop to delete bookmarks in pdf using javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, pdf, adobe, document

There are unnecessary and a large amount of lower-level bookmarks that I am attempting to remove. The for loop returns only the last lower-level bookmark and I have no clue why. I have the code that I was using below:

```js
// Calling the bookmarks
var bm = this.bookmarkRoot; 

//getting the length of the lower level bookmarks
var bmlength = bm.children[0].children[0].children.length; 

// attempting to gather all the bookmarks to delete
for (var i=0; i < bmlength; i++){
var removeMe=bm.children[0].children[0].children[i];
}
removeMe.remove()
```

```html
<!-- Please replace me with example HTML -->
```

Comment: Could you please add the html to your code thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each interation you overwrite `removeMe` and that is the reason why you remove only the last one.

Just call remove inside the loop on every child.

```
for (var i = 0; i < bmlength; i++){
    bm.children[0].children[0].children[i].remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for (var i=0; i < bmlength; i++){
   var removeMe=bm.children[0].children[0].children[i];
   removeMe.remove() 
}
```

or this

```
for (var i=0; i < bmlength; i++){
   bm.children[0].children[0].children[i].remove();
}
```

Comment: `removeMe` is visible outside of the loop because it is declared with `var` not with `let`. A `var` declarition is function not block-scoped